# Is "I am optimistic that <something will happen>" correct?

Tags: grammaticality

Is it grammatically correct to say the following?

> I am optimistic that compilers will improve their error messages in the future.

Comment: Yes good; or I am confident that compilers will...

Comment: @Josh61 I consider "optimistic" in this use to mean "hopeful".  In your experience does it more commonly mean "confident"?

Comment: Well, I'd say that "confident" is very much used to express a sense of hope in something or someone.

Comment: @Josh61 OK.  That makes sense.  It seems to imply more certainty, but this is a nuance with which others may not agree.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a perfectly acceptable usage.

Here's a great example from Natan Sharansky:

> I am optimistic that peace can be achieved in the region because I believe that every society on earth can be free and that if freedom comes to the Middle East, there can be peace.